# Splitscreen Minecraft text entry on Xbox using ChatPad: does it still take over the whole screen?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In split screen multi-player Minecraft on the Xbox 360, when one user needs to enter text (making a sign, naming a weapon on an anvil) the whole screen is taken over by that player's on-screen keyboard. And this is really annoying for the other players.

Is that still the case if that player has a ChatPad keyboard on their controller? Or does that player's text entry happen within their own part of the screen, while the other players play on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the Xbox "keyboard" and it comes up when a game or app wants to use it.

The Xbox keyboard takes up the whole screen and both players can control it. You can also control it with a Xbox or USB keyboard.

I would recommend making everything else with them, and waiting to add the signs when they leave.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on this for the benefit of others: I went ahead and got the ChatPad units, and they work exactly as I'd hoped. Signs can now be edited directly within the user's own screen quadrant, with no impact on other players. The Xbox on-screen keyboard never appears, the text goes right onto the sign. This is with the version of Minecraft Xbox 360 current as of December 2014 and subsequent.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could mark your own answer as "accepted," so that it'll help future visitors know that you've found a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will still take over the whole screen. The only advantage is that you can type faster so it will go away quicker.